# Azure AD Connect 1 Active Directory to 2 tenants, same user synchronized to the 2 tenants

Tags: active-directory, azure-active-directory

I know that Microsoft doesn't support one Active Directory connected (through 2 AADC agents) to two tenants and synchronise the same user to the 2 tenants, but have someone tested it ?

I need to migrate users from tenant1 to tenant2. These users are in AD and already synced to tenant1 through AADC.

I was thinking of the following process :

1> Install a new AADC agent to synchronize from AD to tenant2 --> Not supported by MS

2> Users will have tenant2 .onmicrosoft.com domain name in tenant2 AAD, as SMTP domain is still linked to tenant1

3> I use third party tool to migrate users content (mbx, onedrive...) from tenant1 to tenant2

4> On migration date I renamed objets in tenant1, remove smtp domain name from tenant1 and associate it to tenant2

5> On the next sync sycle AADC rename users in tenant2 for them to have their real SMTP address.

As there is a difference between "not supported" and "not working", I was wonderning if someone already tested this process

Thank you,

Answer (score 0):

I would suggest you take make use of software developed by Bittitan for Tenant to Tenant migrations. Installing 2 AADC agents will put you in a situation where you put yourself in danger by using a not supported scenario.

Below you will find the link:
https://www.bittitan.com/migrationwiz/office-365-tenant-migrations/

Comment: For sure I need a content copy tool, but I don't think Bittitan will take care of my Azure AD objects between previous and new tenant.
Anyway I'm going to look further in their documentation.

Thank you

Comment: Did you find a method to do this? I am faced with the same challenge. What approach did you use for these users in the same on premise AD with a different tenant? Thank you.